# How can I clear an option HTML object with jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I would like to clear and reset the option html object with jquery mobile but I haven't had any luck. It works good with pure jQuery but not with jQuery mobile.

This is my HTML sample code:

```
<select id="CuisineList">
    <option> HI </option>
</select>
```

and my javascript code:

```
$('#CuisineList')
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                ;
```

this is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGgkE/1176/):

If I uncheck the jquery mobile option it works, so I'm looking for a work around on how to approach this.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to `refresh` or re-init the select object so that it redraws basically. Looking up the exact command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to `refresh` the Select Menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CuisineList')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end();
    $("#CuisineList").selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

Forked: http://jsfiddle.net/oykv8193/

http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh